# #include "SDL_image.h" is messing up my compiling

Tags: c++, sdl

I followed this guide http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson03/windows/codeblocks/index.php to set up the sdl image extension but now when i compile anything with #include "SDL_image.h"  it gives me the error "cannot find -lSD" what can i do to fix this?

Comment: Did you mess up linking the library by any chance? Maybe you mean `-lSDL` for linking and added `-ISD` by mistake? Providing more info about exact error message & code snippet might be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure that your linker options are correct, so you would put the flags:

-lSDLmain -lSDL -lSDL_image

and that you actually have these files (they will be either .so or .lib files) somewhere that the compiler can see them. If they are not in the directory where the IDE checks then you will need to specify the location with the -L flag. The -L flag works like so: -L"/path/to/lib/here/"

As you are getting "cannot find -lSD" it would suggest that you may have accidentally put -lSD instead of the full name of -lSDL.

Comment: Exactly it but now when i run source code at the button of the site it tells me "undefined reference to `IMG_Load'" have any idea what might be causing that?
by the way thanks for your well written helpful response

Comment: @user1224829 Usually an undefined reference comes from not linking properly or at all. Have you put **-lSDL_image** in along with **-lSDL**? Also make sure that the library is present with the exact same method as described above.

Answer (score 0):

```
-lmingw32 -lSDLmain -lSDL -lSDL_image
```

Then the link will work!

```
-lmingw32-lSDLmain-lSDL-lSDL_image
```

get nothing...